# When am I supposed to get an acknowledgement for a paper submitted via e-mail (CS conference)?

Tags: conference, computer-science

I have submitted a paper to a CS conference. Am I supposed to get an acknowledgement email, so I know it hasn't ended up in the spam folder by accident, and that it will be considered for the conference? If so, how long after submission? Is it OK to contact the conference organizers and ask if my submission has been received?

Comment: Is there an online submission system? At every conference I ever submitted to, I could inspect the data of my submitted paper after submission.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: As far as I can discern, there's only an email address.

Comment: So you submitted the paper via e-mail? That sounds really untypical for me for a CS conference. But yes, in this case, I would absolutely ask for a confirmation that your submission has been received.

Comment: @Buffy Sure, just waiting for confirmation that the paper was submitted via e-mail. In my area in computer science, that would be super unusual.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: I submitted by email, as per the "Submission Process" instructions on the conference's website.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, and it might be a low quality conference, or even one (in cs) that runs a bit differently from others. Patterns conferences are quite a bit different, though high quality.

Comment: Thanks EvanAad and @Buffy, I now added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In computer science, paper submission by e-mail is non-standard. Therefore, there is no default answer to your question.

However, it's in the interest of the conference organizers to show good professional communication that does not leave authors "in the dark". I would expect them to confirm your submission immediately after submission, within 24 hours. If you have not heard back from them after 24 hours, it's absolutely OK to contact them.

Comment: Actually, they _should_ have an auto-reply in place on the submission email, but probably don't. But maybe they are just new at this.

Comment: @Buffy Alternatively, they might do a manual sanity check of some sorts. But then, they should at least announce the communication protocol (including confirmation e-mails) in the call for papers.

Comment: I browsed the website of the previous time this conference was held, and they did use an online submission system. Strange.

Comment: @EvanAad Maybe the license expired or they didn't like the system. But strange indeed.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I get the feeling that the conference organizers simply haven't set up the online submission system yet, but that they plan on doing so in the future. I think maybe I'm being overly enthusiastic by trying to submit my paper too early, and I should wait for the right time when the paper submission system has been set up. On the other hand, the official conference website is already up, so one could expect the paper submission system to be up as well, and, if not, that there will be a clear notification on the website stating when the system will be available.

Comment: @EvanAad That would still be rather unusual on the conference organizer's side, as this would create some extra effort for adding the e-mailed papers (and meta-data) to the system. Your best bet is to just ask.

Comment: I asked, and, as I suspected, the answer was: "Thé EasyChair will be open soon."